# Wildcards for Azure Data Lake Store inputs in Data Factory

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake

I'm looking at the Microsoft documentation on [moving data to and from an Azure Data Lake Store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-azure-datalake-connector) and finding the following about the `fileName` property:

> Name of the file in the Azure Data Lake store. `fileName` is optional and case-sensitive. If you specify a filename, the activity (including Copy) works on the specific file."

What I don't see here is any mention of wildcards. How do I go about using, for example, not all of the files in a folder but only those matching `2017-foo-*.json`? I tried the asterisk but it appears to be taken literally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your source and sink, you might be able to use the `fileFilter` property instead of the fileName to use wildcards, eg quote from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-onprem-file-system-connector):

> Allowed values are: * (multiple characters) and ? (single character).
>
> Example 1: "fileFilter": "*.log"
>
> Example 2: "fileFilter":
>   2014-1-?.txt"
>
> Note that fileFilter is applicable for an input FileShare dataset.

This example is for an on-prem fileshare:

```
{
    "name": "InputDataset-AllFiles",
    "properties": {
        "published": false,
        "type": "FileShare",
        "linkedServiceName": "OnPremisesFileServerLinkedService",
        "typeProperties": {
            "fileFilter": "*.txt",
            "folderPath": "."
        },
        "availability": {
            "frequency": "Day",
            "interval": 1
        },
        "external": true,
        "policy": {}
    }
}
```

I'm not sure this property is available for other types like blob storage, data lake etc  Can you confirm your source and sink (assuming one of them is data lake)?

Further info available here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/data-factory-onprem-file-system-connector

[Polybase now supports ADLS](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/blog/sql-data-warehouse-now-supports-seamless-integration-with-azure-data-lake-store/) so you could move data in that way without these ADF shenanigans.

Comment: Source is Data Lake Store. Sink is Data Warehouse.

Comment: Polybase now supports ADLS so you could move data in that way without these ADF shenanigans.